# Masking values in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the foll. code in numpy:

```
mask_cntr = np.copy(map_ccodes)
mask_cntr[mask_cntr == cntr] = 1.0
mask_cntr[mask_cntr != 1.0] = 0.0
```

Here, I am copying the 2D array `map_ccodes` to `mask_cntr`, and assigning the values that equal `cntr` in that array to `1.0`, and all others to `0.0`.

Is there a faster and more pythonic way to do this in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function accepts conditions and returns an output based on the condition being True or False:

```
np.where(mask_cntr == cntr, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
mask_cntr = 1.0*(map_ccodes==cntr)
```

I am assuming that `cntr == 1` from your code?

Why do you need a separate mask anyway? You can always use the `map_ccodes==cntr` argument anywhere ...